# Training RPN only with Faster R-CNN

Tags: computer-vision, deep-learning, caffe, object-detection, pycaffe

I'm trying to evaluate the accuracy of the region proposal network only, i.e., prediction whether a bounding box contains an object or not (which does not include the object detection part). However in the script provided does not separate RPN with the detection part.
I wonder if anyone has tried this please share how to do it.